# Netsuite client scripting using tags

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to use ol and ul tags in client script pageInit function to apply them on a textbox in netsuite through scripting,they are getting applied on textbox but the record print is throwing errors

```
function pageInit()
{
var nCustomForm = nlapiGetFieldText('customform');
  if(nCustomForm == 'Flow Quote Form')
  {
  var nFlowQuote = '<ol><li>Example text</li></ol>'; 
  nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_ed_introduction', nFlowQuote);
  }
}
```

want help.

Comment: You’d have to show a little more about what you are doing. How are you trying to apply the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that nCustomForm has exactly that value?
I do this sort of thing fairly regularly but I make sure my inline text field has some default html set on the server and then I use jQuery to find and set the value:

e.g. make sure custbody_ed_introduction is an inline html type field and has a value like

```
<div id='ed_intro_content'></div>
```

You can set that as a default on the field or with a Before Load User Event script. Then in your pageInit script

```
if(nCustomForm == 'Flow Quote Form'){
  $('#ed_intro_content').append($('<ol><li>Example text</li></ol>'));
}
```

Comment: can we use this for dynamic text on the field? I just want the text to be aligned properly so i am using ol/ul tags

Comment: Yes. Once you have an element you can interact with then it’s just like normal HTML